# Is this the best way to rotate the below AVL tree?

Tags: tree, avl-tree

[image: original avl tree]

In an exam paper I had following AVL tree. Need to insert 27 and 69 and check what type of rotation that is needed. My answer:

I inserted 27 on the right of 23 and 69 on the right of 67.

So far the answer should be good. my only problem is how to rotate this . I was thinking to rotate it into the following
[image: rotate]

Can someone confirm this is the best way to do it since i am still shaky in this topic! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed how the AVL tree will be balanced. The insertion of 69 will (should!) trigger a **simple left-rotation**, as also pictured on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Simple_rotation), where  , , and <sub>4</sub> correspond to respectively 54, 67 and 69 in your tree:

[image]